# Spring Data Rest: JOIN search by parent column is throwing error (o.s.d.r.w.RepositoryRestExceptionHandler : PersistentEntity must not be null!)

Tags: spring-data-rest

I am using Spring Data Rest for a Department-Employee relationship as shown below, and have a RepositoryRestResource defined on Employee.

```
class Department {
  @Id
  UUID Id;

  String name;

  @OneToMany(mappedBy = "employee", targetEntity = Employee.class, cascade = {CascadeType.ALL}, fetch = FetchType.LAZY)
  @RestResource(exported = false)
  private Set<Employee> employees;

}


class Employee {
  @Id
  UUID Id;

  String firstName;

  String lastName;

  @ManyToOne(fetch = FetchType.LAZY)
  @JoinColumn(name = "dept_ref")
  @RestResource(exported = false)
  private Department department;
}

@Projection(name = "employeeProjection", types = {Employee.class})
interface EmployeeProjection {
  String getFirstName();
  String getLastName();
}


@RepositoryRestResource(excerptProjection = EmployeeProjection.class)
public interface EmployeeRepository extends CrudRepository<Employee, UUID> {

  //this doesn't work
  @Query(value = "SELECT emp.firstName as firstName , emp.lastName as lastName FROM Employee emp JOIN emp.department "
          + "WHERE emp.department.name = :departmentName ")
  List<EmployeeProjection> findByDepartmentName(@Param("departmentName") String departmentName); 


  //this works
  List<EmployeeProjection> findByFirstName(@Param("firstName") String firstName);

}
```

Issue is when I perform a join search as findByDepartmentName, I am getting below error.

```
2019-07-01 00:26:33.300 ERROR 7396 --- [nio-8443-exec-5] o.s.d.r.w.RepositoryRestExceptionHandler : PersistentEntity must not be null!

java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: PersistentEntity must not be null!
        at org.springframework.util.Assert.notNull(Assert.java:134)
        at org.springframework.data.rest.webmvc.PersistentEntityResource$Builder.<init>(PersistentEntityResource.java:140)
```

Answer (score 0):

the issue got resolved by changing the return type to `List<Employee>` from `List<EmployeeProjection>`, also it still returns me the projection as its an `excerptProjection`. not sure why the Spring Data Rest expects this but it works.

```
List<Employee> findByDepartmentName(@Param("departmentName") String departmentName);
```